# GCP Secret Manager works on Local build but not on GCP Cloud RUN

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, google-cloud-run, google-secret-manager

I can pull all the secrets when running on the local machine when the image is pushed to the Artifact Registry and deployed to Cloud Run. It is unable to access secrets.

I use the application.properties to fetch secrets.

```
spring.config.import=sm://
my.secret.key=${sm://my_key}
```

Error Log:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.cache.RedisService]: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mail.MailSenderAutoConfiguration
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:544) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.lambda$processGroupImports$1(ConfigurationClassParser.java:746) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.processGroupImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:743) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorHandler.process(ConfigurationClassParser.java:714) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:183) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:416) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:289) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:349) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:118) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:788) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
at com.mj.demo.demoApplication.main(demoApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at com.mj.demo.demoApplication.main(demoApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
```

Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission 'secretmanager.versions.access' denied for resource 'projects/demo/secrets/email_host/versions/latest' (or it may not exist).
at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:533) ~[grpc-api-1.61.0.jar:1.61.0]
... 17 common frames omitted

Comment: You have to give the CR permission to access the secret/version.  You can do this at the project level, or put the permission directly on the secret/version by adding the SA running the CR to the secret/version as an sm iam binding with the role `roles/secretmanager.secretAccessor`.

Comment: That's given already. Verified again. All set. Yet it throws an access error.

Comment: @Manoj, have you also checked this documentation on [configuring secrets](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/services/secrets) as you may have missed a step or two?

Comment: Thanks for your time Robert and User51. I removed all the permissions and just added again the same permission. Now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Posting as a community wiki based on the comment of @User51 and confirmed by @Manoj that it is already fixed:

- Cloud Run must be given permission to access the secret/version through either project level or adding `roles/secretmanager.secretAccessor` in the service account.
- Providing documentation on [configuring secrets](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/services/secrets) as there might be some steps that may have been missed.
- This was resolved by removing and adding all permissions.